# Retrieve regex full match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm new in regex expressions. I've read the documentation but I still have some questions.

I Have the following string:

```
[('15000042', 19)]
```

And I need to get the key, the comma and the value as a string.
like this:

```
15000042,19
```

I need this to enter these value as a comma separated value in a database.

I've tried the next regular expression:

```
([\w,]+)
```

but this only split the string into 3 substrings. Is there a way to get the full match?

https://regex101.com/r/vtYKOG/1

I'm using python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You match what you don't want to keep and use 3 groups instead of 1 and assemble your value using these 3 groups:

```
\[\('(\d+)'(,) (\d+)\)\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yjsCmu/1)

For example:

```
import re

test_str = "[('15000042', 19)]"
result = re.sub(r"\[\('(\d+)'(,) (\d+)\)\]", r"\1\2\3", test_str)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Result

```
15000042,19
```

Another option is to use only your character class `[^\w,]+` and negate it so match not what is listed.

Then replace those characters with an empty string:

```
import re

test_str = "[('15000042', 19)]"
result = re.sub(r"[^\w,]+", "", test_str)

if result:
    print (result)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RrpVXp/1)

Comment: Thank you very much, I think is better the second case since it fits my needs.